# If $Ax+By+C=0$ and $x\cos\omega+y\sin\omega=p$ represent the same line, then $\frac{A}{\cos\omega}=\frac{B}{\sin\omega}=-\frac{C}{p}$. How?

Tags: geometry

I was studying the chapter called "Straight Lines" and in it is a topic called general equation of a straight line which they have expressed in normal form. They have compared the equations 
$$Ax + By + C = 0 \quad\text{and}\quad x\cos\omega + y\sin\omega = p \tag{1}$$ In the next step, they have written 
$$\frac{A}{\cos\omega} = \frac{B}{\sin\omega} = -\frac{C}{p} \tag{2}$$

I don't understand how they came to this conclusion.

I have even tried dividing the first equation with the second and it didn't work. I understand that they both represent the same straight line. But that step isn't making any sense.

Answer (score 2):

Let's write the two equations side by side like this:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rrrl}
Ax & + & By & = -C \\
\cos{\omega}~x &+& \sin{\omega}~y &= p
\end{array}
\right.
$$
We want these both to be true for any values of $x,y$. Therefore, we can plug in any values and these both should be true. If we set $x=x_0$ and $y=0$, for example, we get
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rrrl}
A x_0& & & = -C \\
\cos{\omega}~x_0 && &= p
\end{array}
\right.
$$
which leads to $x_0 = \frac{-C}{A} = \frac{p}{\cos{\omega}}$. The other relation is found similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Two lines $AX+BY+C=0$ and $A'X+B'Y+C'=0$ are parallel if and only if $AB'-A'B=0$.

Assuming the lines are not parallel to either axis, the coefficients of $x$ and $y$ are both nonzero and the condition of parallelism can be written
$$
\frac{A}{A'}=\frac{B}{B'}
$$
The lines are the same if they're parallel and have a common point; check that the additional condition becomes
$$
\frac{A}{A'}=\frac{B}{B'}=\frac{C}{C'}
$$
(provided $C'\ne0$).